# Evaluating Riemann Sum

Tags: real-analysis, limits, summation

This question is from Kenneth Ross' Intro to Real Analysis book.

> Evaluate
> $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n+k}$$

So far what I have is if $a_i$ is $\frac{1}{n+i}$, $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_i = 0$, which would mean the limit of the entire sum is zero. This doesn't seem right to me - the hint I was given for it was to write it as a Riemann sum and then express it as an integral, which makes this answer too easy. Is this correct, and if not, how do I express this as a Riemann sum?

Comment: Hint: for any fixed $n$, do you know what $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac1{n+k}$ equals?

Comment: Are you sure the sum has to go to infinity? Because as you wrote it, the series diverges for every constant $n$.

Comment: In fact, I suspect there is a typo in your question, because as it stands this does not have anything to do with Riemann sums.

Comment: Your sum as wirttten in the OP is $\infty$. I think you meant something like $\sum^{n}_{k=1}\frac{1}{n+k}=\frac{1}{n}\sum^n_{k=1}\frac{1}{1+(k/n)}\approx\int^1_0\frac{1}{1+x}\,dx$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find the limit $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k+n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1351714/find-the-limit-lim-n-to-infty-sum-k-1n-frac1kn) If there is no typo then this is **not** the duplicate we are looking for.

Comment: @player3236 there was a typo, this does indeed answer it. Tysm