# How to convert $\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k + n}$ into a definite integral?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, riemann-sum

I am preparing for my Calculus exam, but am stuck on a question where I need to convert the limit of a Riemann sum to a definite integral.

I usually am able to tackle similar questions, but am stuck on this one. I understand that I need to factor $\Delta{x} = \frac{1}{n}$ out of the expression, giving me

$$
\frac{1}{k + n} = \frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{n}{k + n}\right).
$$

However, this is where I am stuck at. I know that in the parentheses, I need to be able to acquire $\frac{k}{n}$ to be the $x$ value also, but I don't see how one can do that from $\frac{n}{k + n}$.

I would appreciate any help or advice pointing me in the right direction.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find the limit $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k+n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1351714/find-the-limit-lim-n-to-infty-sum-k-1n-frac1kn)

Comment: $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+x} \, dx$, Just take n common, you get a $\frac{k}{n}$ factor which converts to x and $\frac{1}{n}$ as n approaches infinity becomes dx and summation becomes integral and your answer is $ln2$

Comment: Please fix the limit expression it is most probably $n$ not $x$.

Comment: Thank you! Done. @NoChance

Comment: Thanks for the response and help. I really appreciate it. @User0

Comment: Yeah it does! Thank you so much, I really appreciate it. @AnotherUser